# How do I add a user to multiple groups

Tags: active-directory, powershell-3.0

I want to specify a source user and capture the list of the groups that user belongs to. I want to then specify a second user and have the original captured groups added to the new users account.

If user1 is a member of GroupA, GroupB, GroupC I want the script to capture that and add it to user3 when I type his name.

```bsh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$SourceUser = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the username of the user whos groups you would like to copy'
$DestUser = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the username of the user who will get: $SourceUser groups"

$SourceGroups = Get-ADUser $SourceUser -Property MemberOf | % {
    $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select Name | sort name
}

"List of groups for user $DestUser BEFORE script: "
Get-ADUser $DestUser -Property MemberOf | % {
    $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select Name | sort name
}

# ***Where my problem is***
#Add-ADGroupMember $SourceGroups –Member $DestUser

"List of groups for user $DestUser AFTER script: "
Get-ADUser -Identity $DestUser -Property MemberOf | % {
    $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select Name | sort name
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected code that now works.

```
    $T2FolderExists = Test-Path "C:\T2\"
$LogsFolderExists = Test-Path "C:\T2\Logs\"

IF ($T2FolderExists -eq $False)
{

    New-Item C:\T2\  -type directory
        IF ($LogsFolderExists -eq $False)
        {
            New-Item C:\T2\Logs\ -type directory
        }
        ELSE
        {
        }
"`n" 
Start-Transcript -Path C:\T2\Logs\CopyMembershipFromADAccount.txt -Append
"`n"
}
ELSE
{
    "`n" 
    Start-Transcript -Path C:\T2\Logs\CopyMembershipFromADAccount.txt -Append
    "`n"
}

<#*****Session Paramaters*****>
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force
Import-Module ActiveDirectory


Clear-Host
Write-Host "Enter the username of the user whos groups you would like to copy" -foregroundcolor Green -backgroundcolor Black
$SourceUser = Read-Host
"`n"

Write-Host "Enter the username of the user who will get: $SourceUser groups" -foregroundcolor Green -backgroundcolor Black
$DestUser = Read-Host
"`n"

$SourceGroups = Get-ADUser $SourceUser -Property MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
$_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select Name -ExpandProperty Name | sort name
}


"`n`n"
Write-Host "List of groups for user $SourceUser BEFORE script: "
Get-ADUser $SourceUser -Property MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
$_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select Name -ExpandProperty Name | sort name
}
"`n`n"
Write-Host "List of groups for user $DestUser BEFORE script: "
Get-ADUser $DestUser -Property MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
$_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select Name -ExpandProperty Name | sort name
}
"`n`n"

ForEach ($Group in $SourceGroups)
{
Add-ADGroupMember $Group –Member $DestUser
Write-Host "Adding $Group to $DestUser 's Account" -foregroundcolor Cyan -backgroundcolor Black
}
"`n`n"
Write-Host "List of groups for user $SourceUser BEFORE script: "
Get-ADUser $SourceUser -Property MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
$_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select Name -ExpandProperty Name | sort name
}
"`n`n"
Write-Host "List of groups for user $DestUser AFTER script: "
Get-ADUser $DestUser -Property MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
$_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select Name -ExpandProperty Name | sort name
}


"`n"
Stop-Transcript
Exit
```

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx).

> ### Syntax
>
> `Add-ADGroupMember [-Identity] <ADGroup> [-Members] <ADPrincipal[]> ...`

The `-Identity` parameter (the first argument) takes a single group identity, not a list of identities. To add a user to a list of groups you need a loop:

```
$SourceGroups | ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember $_ –Member $DestUser }
```

Comment: ForEach ($Group in $SourceGroups)
{
Add-ADGroupMember $Group –Member $DestUser
Write-Host "Adding $Group to $DestUser 's Account" -foregroundcolor Cyan -backgroundcolor Black
}

Comment: That's supposed to tell me ... what?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Import-CSV "data.csv" -Delimiter ";" |
 ForEach {`

    $_.Group1,$_.Group2,$_.Group3,$_.Group4,$_.Group5,$_.Group6 |
        Add-ADGroupMember `
            -Members        $_.Alias`
 }
```

You can have more groups in the script without using them.

And in the "data.csv", you put this (for example):

```
Alias;Group1;Group2;Group3;Group4
l.salvador;Spanish;Republic;Central;WWW
```

Although I had an error with "Identity" could not be checked, it worked.